# jquery ajax array inside data array

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I am trying to call ajax using similar parameters:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajax_url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        fields: {
            id: id,
            name: name
        }
    }
});
```

This doesnt seem to work. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why not just `data: {id: id, name: name}` ?

Comment: because then i need to extract them one by one, but if i pass an array, i can just use that for simplicity

Comment: You can't pass an array like it is, you have to serialize(convert to a String) and then unserialize. So, I suggest you not to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What is the server on the other end?  This should work fine, it's the server's fault! :-P

Comment: well, i'm only guessing that it doesn't work because the ajax query never completes. when i remove it, then it works fine. *shrugs* the server is apache..

Comment: after logging the requests made to the ajax file it seems the parameters are passed normally. so to sum it up, the problem is not this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your server is expecting JSON, you need to stringify it:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajax_url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        fields: {
            id: id,
            name: name
        }
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

Make sure you include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) if you need this to work on old browsers.

When you attempt to post without stringifying your javascript object and marking the `contentType`, it writes the request as URL-encoded parameters, which get all funky on complex object types. Take a look at the request body in your browser dev tools or Fiddler to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array, however it has to be in a specific format:

```
[
    {
        name: "thefieldname",
        value: "thefieldvalue"
    },
    {
        name: "anotherfieldname",
        value: "anotherfieldvalue"
    }
]
```

this will later be converted to a query string such as `"thefieldname=thefieldvalue"` when sent to the server. If you wish to send more than the name and value, you'll need to instead send JSON to the server.

```
data: { json: JSON.stringify(myobjectorarray) }
```

and access it from the `json` post variable server-side.